# how to get the dependencies of a project with a package-lock.json but no package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project with a package-lock.json but no package.json.

When I run `npm install` I get the following:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/neubert/myproject/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/neubert/myproject/package.json'
npm WARN myproject No description
npm WARN myproject No repository field.
npm WARN myproject No README data
npm WARN myproject No license field.

up to date in 0.279s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Any ideas how I can make it so that the deps in the package-lock.json are downloaded, even if package.json isn't present?

Answer (score 1):

Well my first thought would be to run
`npm rebuild`

If you have installed previously it will rebuild all the packages and they will print out on your screen. Then its just a matter of adding them back to a package.js

here is a link to [npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands)  and their cli commands... its handy.  i have it bookmarked in my cheat sheets